# Numpy cannot always convert a list of arrays to an object-array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Python 3 version 3.8.10, numpy version 1.19.5

I expected this code

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((2,1))
b = np.ones((2,3))
c = [a,b]
print(np.asarray(c,dtype='object'))
```

to print the same thing as

```py
d = np.empty((2,),dtype='object')
d[:] = a,b
print(d)
```

that is:

```py
[array([[1.],
       [1.]]) array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])]
```

.

Instead, it raises a ValueError:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_35004/192805992.py in <module>
      3 b = np.ones((2,3))
      4 c = [a,b]
----> 5 print(np.asarray(c,dtype='object'))

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,1) into shape (2)
```

This issue does not occur when the lengths of the first dimension of the arrays contained in the list differ.

This is a problem when converting a list-of-arrays to an object-array of arrays, where the first dimension of all arrays could be the same.

Previously, Numpy would convert ragged lists-of-arrays to a ragged object-array-of-arrays. This behavior has been deprecated. Sadly, the suggested fix of specifying the array to be of type "object" does not always work.

What is the current idiom for this conversion?

Comment: This has always been a problem.  The 'ragged warning' did not change anything.

Comment: You have already identified the right way, the one starting with the `np.empty(x, object)` array.  That's the only one that ever worked reliably, regardless of the mix of dimensions.  `np.array` is designed to create a multidimensional numeric array.  Handling mixed shapes is a fall-back option, which works with some shapes, and fails with others.

Comment: Hmm; I had a project that was working using the old behavior. It stopped working, giving this ragged warning. It could be a coincidence, but I haven't had time to think about this thoroughly and won't have time to work on this in detail for several weeks. If it is useful: the old code wrapped the `array` conversion in a try-catch, and then defaulted to casting to an object array if this failed. Perhaps there is some edge case where this does something useful that isn't automatically/easily replicating by the new behavior.

Comment: I think the ragged warning was added in version 1.17.  But other than that, I'm not aware of any changes in the behavior.  I've answered similar questions long before that.